# Windows Phone Live Tiles with Background from the Web and updated automatically.

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

I am currently working on a windows Phone App that is supposed to have a flipping liveTile. Here's how it is supposed to work:

[image: LiveTile example]

The Front will be generated from UI Elements that are filled with Data pulled from a Web API. That Backside will be generated from an Image downloaded from the Web. the Idea ist to have one Image for the small liveTile size and one for the big live tile.

Can someone give me a hint, how i can update the livetile automatically without having to have the app opened? I can't do it with a Push notification because i don't have a server to do the pushing in the first place. I tried using the ShellTileSheduler and RemotImageURI property but this doesn't work for different sizes. Am i  missing something? Has anyone done somehting like this and has an idea how to do it? I'm getting really frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good start to generate tile

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/04/10/live-apps-creating-custom-tile-and-lock-screen-images.aspx